# showing location on iphone map with a mobile web app

Tags: javascript, iphone, jquery-mobile, maps

I am making a mobile webapp with jquery mobile. On one page I have an city and an address.
What I want to do now is when I push on a button, it automatically opens up the
maps app on my iphone and shows the location.

Does anybody has an idea or some more information about it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Map Links [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html) fully describes your needs.
The specially-formed URL to launch Map application (or any other supporting URL-schemes) might be embedded as a href.